# Joomla 2.5 Plugin Include Component and Direct PHP conflict in articles

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, get

So I'm building a Joomla 2.5 site with both the Plugin Include Component and Direct PHP plugins. I am trying to do the following within an article view:

```
    $lstart = $_GET['lstart'];
    $limitstart = $_GET['limitstart'];

    if($lstart == 1) { ?>
       {component url='index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=15&news_check=1&limitstart=4'}
    <?php } else { ?>
       {component url='index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=15&news_check=1&limitstart=0'}
    <?php } ?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /nfs/c06/h06/mnt/157252/domains/bigideaadv.com/html/wright_specialty2_OLD/plugins/content/DirectPHP/DirectPHP.php(56) : eval()'d code on line 4
```

Can I not mix Plugin Include Component and Direct PHP code together?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this PHP is an exact copy then the problem may be the first `echo` statement having an extra single quote i.e. ' before the closing brace }.

So, if `$limitstart = 10`, the first `echo` would produce:

```
{component url='index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=15&news_check=1&limitstart='10''}
```

This would probably cause problems for the Include Component plug-in. They should be able to run together the only thing would be to ensure that the Direct PHP plug-in is ordered before your other plug-ins.

Comment: I've updated my code slightly. The article component plugin syntax is as such {component url=''}. The unexpected $end is due to premature php close code ?> or no? I would need to shove in a variable in the first part of the if statement for the limitstart, but first things first...